# tcpdf html table rows more then 500 rows results in blank page

Tags: php, pdf, report, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF for PDF reports from database but when in table row limit reaches to 400 its results in blank page.Is there any solution .Please Help

Here is my code.

```
    <?php
$start = microtime(true);
ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
error_reporting(0);
 $username=$_GET['user'];
 $todate=$_GET['date'];
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Karachi");

 /*** PDF Report CODE ****/

  require_once("tcpdf/tcpdf.php");

  class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

    //Page header
    public function Header() {
        // Logo
        $image_file = 'img/pdf_logo.JPG';
        $this->Image($image_file, 10, 10, 25, '', 'JPG', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 20);
        // Title
        $title='

        ';

        $this->Cell(0, 15, 'XYZ ', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');


    }

    // Page footer
    public function Footer()
     {
        // Position at 15 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
        // Page number
        $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
        $this->Ln(4);
        $xfooter=' <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0" align="left">
  <tr align="left"><td colspan="5">'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'</td></tr>
  </table>        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0" align="right">
  <tr align="right"><td colspan="5">Printed by:'.$GLOBALS['username'].' ('.date("Y-m-d h:i:sa").')</td></tr>
  </table>';

        $this->writeHTML($xfooter);

    }
}
$pdf= new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

  // set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('ERP Dashboard');
$pdf->SetTitle('XYZ');
$pdf->SetSubject('test Reports');
$pdf->SetKeywords('test, PDF, test, Reports, dashboard');



// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(5,24,2);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('times', '', 10);      
      $pdf->AddPage('P', 'A4');
      $content = '';
      $content.='
              <h2 style="text-decoration: underline;" align="center"><b> Allocated/Unallocated Stock Report for-'.$GLOBALS['todate'].'</b></h2>  
                                <table border="1px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="95%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>    
                                        <th rowspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">Sr.</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">Item Id</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">Item Description</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">Category</th>

                                        <th colspan="2" align="center" class="text-center">
                                            Allocated Qty 
                                        </th>
                                       <th colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle"  class="text-center">Unallocated Qty</th>
                                       <th rowspan="2" class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;">Total Stock Qty</th>
                                       <th rowspan="2" class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;">Avg Rate</th>
                                       <th rowspan="2" class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;">Value</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <th  class="center"><small>FOC Wise</small></th>
                                      <th  class="center"><small>Without FOC</small></th>
                                      <th  class="center"><small>FOC Wise</small></th>
                                      <th  class="center"><small>Without FOC</small></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
      ';
      $content .= get_data();  
      $content .= '</table>';  
      $pdf->writeHTML($content);
  $pdf->Output('Allocated/Unallocated_Stock Report-('.$GLOBALS['todate'].').pdf', 'D'); 



 /**** End PDF CODE******/


 ?>
```

I am using TCPDF for PDF reports from database but when in table row limit reaches to 400 its results in blank page.Is there any solution .Please Help

Here is my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. It will work. You have to set 'memory_limit' high.

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit', '10000000');
ini_set('memory_limit', '4060M');
```